# Print just class name in EL

Tags: jsp, el, classname

I have an EL variable `${foo}` in my JSP page. I want to print out the class name of the variable. I have tried:

```
${foo['class']}
```

Which works just fine but it prints this exact text out:

```
class app.test.model.Foo
```

However I just want it to print out the `Foo` part and not the rest of it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is EL, not JSTL. To learn what exactly JSTL is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info I fixed the terminology in your question.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for the insight! Glad I asked my question here before I said something stupid in public xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This EL expression, `${foo['class']}`, actually invokes [`Object#getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)  on the `Object` instance represented by `${foo}`. This method returns a [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance which in turn has a [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) method you're looking for.

All in all,

```
${foo['class'].simpleName}
```